# Why does an empty, non-spatial table get flagged as Is_Simple=False in an SQL query?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql, esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I've created an empty table in an Oracle geodatabase. It was created in ArcCatalog by using the catalog tree >> New >> Table tool. The table **is** registered with the geodatabase and **is not** registered as versioned. The only field it has is the default OBJECTID field.

Why does it return False when I run an Is_Simple check? Shouldn't it be returning True, since it doesn't participate in extended geodatabase functionality?

```
SELECT SDE.GDB_UTIL.Is_Simple('ENG', 'TEST_TABLE')
FROM DUAL;

FALSE
```

Environment:

- ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1
- SDE 10.3.1
- Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0)

Source SQL:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/is-simple.htm

Related: What type of data can be edited using SQL?:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-type-of-data-can-be-edited-using-sql.htm

**Update 2016-08-23:**

To test whether this had something to do with being registered with the geodatabase, I created a separate table that was not registered with the geodatabase (used the Create Unregistered Table geoprocessing tool). When I run the SQL query it returns NOT REGISTERED. In my question above, I'm getting FALSE, as opposed to NOT REGISTERED, so I don't think that's the problem; the table is definitely registered with the geodatabase.

Comment: How can you create a table without columns?  The page you reference states that unregistered tables will generate an error.  Has the table in question been registered?

Comment: I've corrected the part in the question about 'no columns'. The table is registered with the database (it was created in the ArcCatalog tree). I've tested a separate table that was not registered with the geodatabase (created with the Create Unregistered Table geoprocessing tool) and it returns NOT REGISTERED, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to contain this information.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to scan comments for critical details .

Comment: @Vince The question has been updated.